# Timeline Of Various Puranas

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, shiva-purana, vishnu-purana, linga-purana

It is well-established by the great yogis, after attaining siddhis, that the stories told in the Puranas are not at all metaphorical and allegorical. It is known when these stories were **revealed**.

However, I propose to ask, **when did all these stories take place on earth?**

For example, the Shiva-Parvati Vivah, Ravan-Shiv milan etc.